# Strip down ubuntu server for performance on virtual machine

Tags: performance, virtual-machines, ubuntu-10.04, virtualbox

We use a ubuntu virtual machine for a local development setup which provides a consistent development environment for all developers and lets them use an OS/IDE of their choice for other work.

The image is based on ubuntu server 10.04 and runs on VirtualBox.

Are there any extra packages/processes that can be stripped or some tweaks which can be applied to reduce memory/cpu usage by the virtual machine for a better development experience?

Comment: This is a good starting point
http://askubuntu.com/questions/320903/usb-drive-with-stripped-down-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press F4 at the install screen of Ubuntu Server Edition and choose a minimal install. You can also use vmbuilder to build an ISO with the minimal packages needed for a VM.

See here for more info:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/jeos-and-vmbuilder.html
- http://www.ubuntu.com/business/server/virtualisation